# Translate Htaccess line of code, confused by regex, handle letters versus numbers differently

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have this line of code in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^url/([\w\d]{6})$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I understand that it's rewriting the url from `site.com/url/wkwkwk` to `site.com/page.php?id=wkwkwk`

However, I don't understand what the `[\w\d]{6}` means.  Begins with W, ends with D and is 6 characters long?  Is that it?

If so, can I add another line that deals only with numerical values like this:

```
RewriteRule ^url/([0-9]+)$ differentpage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So, both lines together would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^url/([\w\d]{6})$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^url/([0-9]+)$ differentpage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Would this work to deal with url/then-some-letters and url/then-some-numbers differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question here with what I learned.

I'm not sure about the \w and \d, but the `{6}` part means 6 characters only.  I was having a problem because I wanted it to be up to 6 characters long.

In order to fix this, I changed the `{6}` to `{0,6}`.